# How to insert or render a template after another template is rendered in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

I've got this layout template:

```
<template name="layout">

  {{> yield }}

  {{> tail }}

</template>
```

Right now Meteor doesn't seem to wait for `{{> yield }}` to be fully rendered before starting to render `{{> tail }}`

This is the tail. The HTML in here needs to be loaded after the rest of the DOM has been created (I'm using a Bootstrap template).

```
<template name="tail">

  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/classie.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>

  <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
  <script src="/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>
  <script src="/js/contact_me.js"></script>

  <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
  <script src="/js/agency.js"></script>

</template>
```

How would I get the HTML inside of `tail.html` to be rendered after all the other templates have been rendered?

I can use:

```
Template.layout.rendered = function(){

    var scripts = '\
  <!-- Plugin JavaScript -->\
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>\
  <script src="/js/classie.js"></script>\
  <script src="/js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>\
  \
  <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->\
  <script src="/js/jqBootstrapValidation.js"></script>\
  <script src="/js/contact_me.js"></script>\
  \
  <!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->\
  <script src="/js/agency.js"></script>\
    ';

    $('body').append(scripts);

};
```

But this is ugly. It breaks the tail code into a string, forces you to add `\`, makes it really hard to edit the code later on.

Comment: You could add the scripts normally in your tail template and only initialize them on the rendered event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onreadystatechange = function() {
    // if (this.readyState == 'complete') { callFunctionFromScript(); }
}
script.src = 'path/to/your-script.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

u can directly apped it into html head tag inside

```
Template.layoutHeader.rendered = function() { .. }
```